# Font messed up after kubuntu-desktop installed

Tags: unity, 12.10, kde, fonts

I wanted to try kde, so I installed `kubuntu-desktop`, I didn't like it so I removed.

That messed up my font configuration in Ubuntu. Firefox and menu bar are ok, however, the rest (Eclipse, Monodevelop, lipiks, All message boxes...) I need help please.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/225600/44179