# KDE theme appears in Unity, Cinnamon, and XFCE

Tags: unity, 12.10, kde, cinnamon

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 with Unity, Cinnamon, XCFE, and KDE installed. Every time I run KDE, the KDE theme appears in all the applications when run on any of the other desktops. I'd really appreciate it if I could get this fixed. If a picture would be helpful, I can add one. Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/q/225600/44179) question has a fix.  It only works once per login though.

Comment: sorry, I miss-worded that.  It only works once per login.  So you need to repeat it every login.  That is why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: Actually, feel free to post it as an answer. It did work even though I logged in again. Thanks!

Comment: Login to KDE then log back into Unity.  KDE overwrites the theme files.

Comment: Yes, it will. But I was only concerned about the Unity files, so it doesn't matter to me. I understand KDE will overwrite them, but I don't use KDE a lot, so it will work great. You supplied the answer I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you delete any `.gtkrc` files in your `HOME` directory and then select an Ambiance theme it will rewrite the theme files with Unity presets.

Note:  files beginning with a `.` (period) are hidden.  To view them in Nautilus press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> or use `ls -a` in a terminal.

Comment: Did not work for me.