# Unity and KDE desktop on the same screen

Tags: unity, kde, desktop-environments

As you can see in the screenshot below, the user has managed to run KDE desktop in Unity (or vice versa?)

[image: screenshot]

I've already installed `kubuntu-desktop` package and CompizConfig Settings Manager and also able to switch to KDE desktop separately but couldn't find a way to run both on same screen.

So my question is, how to get this done?

Comment: Based on pure theory, I think this can be achieved by running `nohup plasma-desktop &` in a terminal from within Unity. (try that - I'm too lazy here too install 1000+MB of packages on my virtual machine, so not posting as an answer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [KDE theme appears in Unity, Cinnamon, and XCFE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/234840/kde-theme-appears-in-unity-cinnamon-and-xcfe)

Comment: @EricCarvalho What? Read the question again! OP **wants** to mix two DEs in one. It's not about a mixed appearance in themes.

Comment: @gertvdijk Thanks that worked. Let me reboot and i'll let you know if this is persistent.

Comment: @gertvdijk My bad. I thought he wanted to get rid of it.

Comment: @gertvdijk How to make this code run on every reboot and also, is it possible to run it within KDE like `nohup unity-desktop &`?

Comment: @Adige72 I'm not sure about the other way around. I believe this is possible similarly, but using `unity` instead of `plasma-desktop`. Try it out and update my answer if that works. :)

Comment: @gertvdijk Sorry for late reply, i somehow couldn't boot into KDE desktop so i cant try. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I totally don't know why one would want this, it's certainly possible. From a standard Ubuntu (with Unity) installation:

1. Install [kubuntu-desktop [image: Install kubuntu-desktop]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kubuntu-desktop)
2. In a terminal within the Unity desktop, try to run the KDE desktop like this:

   ```
   nohup plasma-desktop &
   ```

   <sup>The `nohup somecommand &` pattern makes it run in the background and independent of the terminal you're running this in. (specifically, the process spawned isn't a child of terminal in the process tree, but given to the mother of all processes - `init`.)</sup>
3. *optional* If you like this and you want to make it permanent you can create a startup script:

   - Create a text file (with for example Gedit) `startkde.sh`, containing

     ```
     #!/bin/bash
     # sleep seems necessary - getting kdeinit I/O errors otherwise
     sleep 3 && /usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/plasma-desktop &
     ```
   - Make the file executable, from Nautilus (file properties), or by running `chmod +x startkde.sh`
   - Open *Startup Applications* from the Dash.
   - Add an entry "KDE" and browse to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to achieve this:

1. Install [kubuntu-desktop](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kubuntu-desktop/)
2. Login with KDE
3. Run `unity` in the terminal

Create an autostart entry in KDE with the command `unity`, if you like.