# Completely Remove Kubuntu Desktop From Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I installed "Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system" from the ubuntu software system to try it out. I prefer Unity and want to remove Kubuntu.

I uninstalled from the Ubuntu software center, but it hasn't worked. During boot I get "Kubuntu" on the screen and not "Ubuntu", also I can log in into Kubuntu and it is working fine.

So how can I remove Kubuntu and all files that came with it?

When trying `sudo apt-get autoremove kubuntu-desktop` I get this message:
`Package 'kubuntu-desktop' is not installed, so not removed`

---

Here is my terminal output after trying the commands `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and
`sudo aptitude remove '?and(?depends(?exact-name(kubuntu-desktop)),?not(?depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'`:

```
darren@darren-K52Jr:~$ sudo apt-get install aptitude
[sudo] password for darren: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
aptitude is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
darren@darren-K52Jr:~$ sudo aptitude remove '?and(?depends(?exact-name(kubuntu-desktop)),?not(?depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

darren@darren-K52Jr:~$
```

---

Using `sudo apt-get --purge remove kubuntu-desktop`, `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `run sudo apt-get autoclean` I get these result:

```
darren@darren-K52Jr:~$ sudo apt-get --purge remove kubuntu-desktop
[sudo] password for darren: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'kubuntu-desktop' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
darren@darren-K52Jr:~$ ^C
darren@darren-K52Jr:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
darren@darren-K52Jr:~$ sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Del python-imaging 1.1.7+2.0.0-1ubuntu1.1 [347 kB]
Del python-imaging-compat 1.1.7+2.0.0-1ubuntu1.1 [5,410 B]
Del libwhoopsie0 0.2.24.1.2 [7,350 B]
Del ubuntu-tweak 0.8.7-0~bzr1993+20140421~ubuntu13.10.1 [994 kB]
Del python3-distupgrade 1:0.205.6 [136 kB]
Del numix-icon-theme 0.3+139~201404162022~ubuntu13.10.1 [3,431 kB]
Del unity 7.2.0+14.04.20140423-0ubuntu1.1 [1,437 kB]
Del unity-services 7.2.0+14.04.20140423-0ubuntu1.1 [29.3 kB]
Del whoopsie 0.2.24.1.2 [26.6 kB]
Del libcurl3 7.32.0-1ubuntu1.4 [198 kB]
Del ubuntu-release-upgrader-core 1:0.205.6 [24.1 kB]
Del flashplugin-installer 11.2.202.350ubuntu0.13.10.1 [6,932 B]
Del libunity-core-6.0-9 7.2.0+14.04.20140423-0ubuntu1.1 [447 kB]
Del numix-gtk-theme 2.2+294~201404131947~ubuntu13.10.1 [41.5 kB]
Del libcurl3-gnutls 7.32.0-1ubuntu1.4 [189 kB]
Del libsnmp30 5.7.2~dfsg-8ubuntu1.1 [1,322 kB]
Del libsnmp-base 5.7.2~dfsg-8ubuntu1.1 [235 kB]
Del ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk 1:0.205.6 [10.5 kB]
darren@darren-K52Jr:~$
```

---

Results for command `sudo aptitude search '?depends(?exact-name(kubuntu-desktop)'`:

```
darren@darren-K52Jr:~$ sudo aptitude search '?depends(?exact-name(kubuntu-desktop)'
[sudo] password for darren: 
E: Match pattern ends unexpectedly (expected ')').
darren@darren-K52Jr:~$
```

Comment: I started this thread because I thought this may be a new issue relating only to 14.04, and that I had no success from the thread you are linking to.

Comment: did you restart your pc after running these commands?

Comment: Yep I rebooted, and I just rebooted again, issue still remains.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get --purge remove kubuntu-desktop` and then `sudo apt-get autoremove` http://superuser.com/questions/30112/kubuntu-to-ubuntu and finally run `sudo apt-get autoclean`

Comment: updated opening post with the results of using these 3 commands

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1349780 and http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu I take no responsibility if that breaks your system

Comment: @Braiam what I don't understand, is if he has kubuntu installed using the live cd, clean installation, why it shows `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.` at least something has to be downloaded after running `sudo aptitude remove '?and(?depends(?exact-name(kubuntu-desktop)),?not(?depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'` unless he has unity by default which is impossible
`

Comment: For a little more info: Several months a go I installed Ubuntu 13.10 onto a partition of my laptop. About a week ago I upgraded to 14.04. Several days ago I installed `Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system` from Ubuntu Software Center, and today I unistalled using Ubuntu software Center (supposedly, plus everything you guys have been helping with. I am going to boot my kubuntu and take a pic of "Kubuntu" on loading, and then a pic when I log into KDE desktop.

Comment: @Braiam added the output to opening post. I am given an `>` looking for use input...

Comment: arrrg! Just close the quote, like this: `sudo aptitude search '?depends(?exact-name(kubuntu-desktop)'`. Sorry was a typo of mine.

Comment: and please never again install DEs from software center, services like mysql or apache and DEs are best installed from terminal, and preferably using aptitude, and they could be easily removed, only God knows what package the software center downloaded on your computer...

Comment: @Braiam, ok, updated opening post with this info.

Comment: Ok, found the problem, check my answer here again: http://askubuntu.com/a/458347/169736

Comment: @Braiam - wonderful that solved the problem! Thank you.

Comment: @Braiam - Interestingly I still get the words "Kubuntu" instead of "ubuntu" on boot and shut down, even though the KDE desktop is now gone.

Comment: That's maybe because plymouth hasn't been removed. Check for the packages called plymouth.

Comment: @Braiam  I have installed: `plymouth`, `plymouth-label`, `plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo`, `plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text`, `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo`and `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text`. Do I simply just uninstall using `apt-get --purge remove plymouth`?

Comment: Unless you want to remove all the plymouth packages, only removing `plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text` should suffice.