# How to get rid of KDE look and feel parts in other DEs?

Tags: desktop-environments

I've installed `kubuntu-desktop` to try. KDE disappointed me, I removed it by means of `sudo apt-get remove --purge kde-*`, then `autoremove` (it is well known that just `sudo apt-get remove --purge kubuntu-desktop` doesn't remove anything). But parts of KDE L&F (icons, fonts&colors) polluted Unity and Xfce environments. It looks really ugly. I've "reinstalled" Unity (`apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`), it doesn't help.

Comment: Why downvote? What is wrong with my question?

Comment: [Probably because there's already another that ask almost the same](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451620/how-to-completely-remove-kubuntu-desktop/458347#458347)

Comment: @Braiam it would be useful before I removed kubuntu my (apparently wrong) way. Not aptitude don't find any kubuntu deps, but L&F remains a crappy mix of kubuntu and unity parts.

Comment: Can you do `aptitude search '?reverse-depends(kubuntu)` and `aptitude search '~Gkde'`.

Comment: It should have been `aptitude search '?reverse-depends(kubuntu)' the first one.

Comment: @Braiam the first command lists a lot of general packages. The second lists nothing.

Comment: Edit your question and add `aptitude search '?and(?reverse-depends(kubuntu), ~i)'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Terminal window and copy/paste this command to remove KDE and it's parts:

```
sudo apt-get remove akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-facebook akonadi-server akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt apport-kde apturl-common apturl-kde ark audiocd-kio bluedevil calligra-data calligra-libs cdparanoia cdrdao colord-kde cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin docbook-xsl dolphin dragonplayer dvd+rw-tools freespacenotifier gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgsm growisofs gstreamer0.10-qapt gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen gwenview ibus-qt4 icoutils jockey-common jockey-kde k3b k3b-data kaccessible kaddressbook kamera kamoso kate kate-data katepart kcalc kde-base-artwork kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-tablet kde-config-telepathy-accounts kde-config-touchpad kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kde-style-oxygen kde-telepathy kde-telepathy-approver kde-telepathy-auth-handler kde-telepathy-contact-list kde-telepathy-data kde-telepathy-filetransfer-handler kde-telepathy-integration-module kde-telepathy-minimal kde-telepathy-send-file kde-telepathy-text-ui kde-wallpapers-default kde-window-manager kde-window-manager-common kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-data kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kde-zeroconf kdegames-card-data kdegames-data kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing kdepasswd kdepim-kresources kdepim-runtime kdepim-strigi-plugins kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdesudo kdoctools kexi khelpcenter4 kinfocenter klipper kmag kmail kmenuedit kmix kmousetool knotes konsole kontact korganizer kpat kppp krdc krita krita-data ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog ktorrent ktorrent-data kubuntu-debug-installer kubuntu-default-settings kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-docs kubuntu-firefox-installer kubuntu-netbook-default-settings kubuntu-notification-helper kubuntu-web-shortcuts kvkbd kwalletmanager libaio1 libakonadi-calendar4 libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4 libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadi-notes4 libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libassuan0 libattica0.4 libaudio2 libaudiocdplugins4 libavahi-gobject0 libbluedevil1 libboost-date-time1.49.0 libboost-program-options1.49.0 libboost-thread1.49.0 libcalendarsupport4 libcanberra-pulse libchm1 libcln6 libclucene0ldbl libcmis-0.2-2 libcrypt-passwdmd5-perl libcryptsetup4 libdbusmenu-qt2 libdebconf-kde0 libdlrestrictions1 libdmtx0a libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libepub0 libeventviews4 libexttextcat-1.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfftw3-3 libflac++6 libgif4 libglew1.8 libgpgme++2 libgpgme11 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgps20 libgrantlee-core0 libgtlcore0.8 libgtlfragment0.8 libhyphen0 libibus-qt1 libilmbase6 libincidenceeditorsng4 libindicate-qt1 libiso9660-8 libk3b6 libkabc4 libkactivities-bin libkactivities6 libkalarmcal2 libkateinterfaces4 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcddb4 libkcmutils4 libkcompactdisc4 libkdcraw-data libkdcraw21 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5 libkdecorations4abi1 libkdecore5 libkdegames6 libkdepim4 libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdgantt2 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkephal4abi1 libkexiv2-11 libkexiv2-data libkfile4 libkgapi0 libkholidays4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkimap4 libkio5 libkipi-data libkipi9 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkleo4 libkmanagesieve4 libkmbox4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkolab0 libkolabxml0 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1 libkontactinterface4 libkparts4 libkpgp4 libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libkrossui4 libksane-data libksane0 libksba8 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4 libksieve4 libksieveui4 libksignalplotter4 libktexteditor4 libktnef4 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent4 libktpchat0 libktpcommoninternalsprivate3 libkunitconversion4 libkwineffects1abi4 libkwinglutils1abi1 libkwinnvidiahack4 libkworkspace4abi2 libkxmlrpcclient4 liblastfm1 liblightdm-qt-2-0 libllvm3.0 liblvm2app2.2 libmailcommon4 libmailimporter4 libmailtransport4 libmessagecomposer4 libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4 libmessageviewer4 libmicroblog4 libmission-control-plugins0 libmng1 libmpcdec6 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libmuonprivate1 libmusicbrainz5-0 libmygpo-qt1 libmysqlclient18 libmythes-1.2-0 libneon27-gnutls libnepomuk4 libnepomukcore4abi1 libnepomukquery4a libnepomuksync4 libnepomukutils4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libokularcore1abi1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenconnect2 libopenctl0.8 libopenexr6 libopenjpeg2 libopenshiva0.8 libphonon4 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasma3 libplasmaclock4abi3 libplasmagenericshell4 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-4 libprison0 libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libpth20 libpython3.2 libqalculate5 libqalculate5-data libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqca2 libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgpgme1 libqimageblitz4 libqjson0 libqoauth1 libqrencode3 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtassistantclient4 libqtcore4 libqtglib-2.0-0 libqtgstreamer-0.10-0 libqtgstreamerui-0.10-0 libqtgui4 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libqtshiva0.1 libqtwebkit4 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-impress libreoffice-kde libreoffice-math libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-writer libruby1.9.1 libsgutils2-2 libsolid4 libsolidcontrol4abi2 libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2 libsoprano4 libspnav0 libssh-4 libstlport4.6ldbl libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libsyndication4 libtag-extras1 libtaskmanager4abi3 libtelepathy-logger-qt4-1 libtelepathy-logger2 libtelepathy-qt4-2 libtemplateparser4 libthreadweaver4 libvcdinfo0 libvirtodbc0 libvncserver0 libweather-ion6 libxerces-c3.1 libxml2-utils libyaml-0-2 libzip2 lightdm-kde-greeter muon muon-installer muon-notifier muon-updater mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.5 nepomuk-core nepomuk-core-data ntrack-module-libnl-0 nvidia-common obexd-client odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 ofono okular okular-extra-backends oxygen-cursor-theme oxygen-icon-theme partitionmanager phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook plasma-scriptengine-javascript plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-widget-facebook plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-kimpanel plasma-widget-menubar plasma-widget-message-indicator plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widget-telepathy-chat plasma-widget-telepathy-presence plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text polkit-kde-1 print-manager pulseaudio-module-bluetooth python-kde4 python-pyudev python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-sip python-uno python-xkit python3-pykde4 python3-pyqt4 python3-sip qapt-batch qapt-deb-installer qdbus quassel quassel-data rdesktop rekonq ruby ruby1.9.1 shared-desktop-ontologies skanlite software-properties-kde soprano-daemon syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy systemsettings tasks-icons telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze telepathy-logger telepathy-mission-control-5 telepathy-ring telepathy-salut ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt udisks uno-libs3 ure usb-creator-common usb-creator-kde userconfig vcdimager virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common wodim xfonts-mathml
```

Comment: Wow, after removing already removed packages from the list, it helped. Thank you.