# Cannot connect to the internet after uninstalling kubuntu-desktop

Tags: networking, kubuntu

I wanted to remove kubuntu desktop and its deps as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/653/148451):

```
sudo apt-get remove akonadi-facebook akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils apport-kde apturl-kde ark audiocd-kio bluedevil calligra-data calligra-libs colord-kde cryptsetup dolphin dragonplayer freespacenotifier gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgsm gstreamer0.10-qapt gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen gwenview ibus-qt4 kaccessible kaddressbook kamera kamoso kate kcalc kde-base-artwork kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-tablet kde-config-telepathy-accounts kde-config-touchpad kde-style-oxygen kde-telepathy kde-telepathy-approver kde-telepathy-auth-handler kde-telepathy-contact-list kde-telepathy-data kde-telepathy-filetransfer-handler kde-telepathy-integration-module kde-telepathy-minimal kde-telepathy-send-file kde-telepathy-text-ui kde-wallpapers-default kde-window-manager kde-window-manager-common kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-data kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kde-zeroconf kdegames-card-data kdegames-data kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing kdepasswd kdepim-kresources kdepim-strigi-plugins kdesudo kexi khelpcenter4 kinfocenter klipper kmag kmail kmenuedit kmix kmousetool knotes konsole kontact korganizer kpat kppp krdc krita krita-data ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog ktorrent ktorrent-data kubuntu-default-settings kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-docs kubuntu-firefox-installer kubuntu-netbook-default-settings kubuntu-notification-helper kubuntu-web-shortcuts kvkbd kwalletmanager libassuan0 libaudiocdplugins4 libbluedevil1 libcalendarsupport4 libchm1 libcln6 libdebconf-kde0 libepub0 libeventviews4 libfftw3-3 libgpgme++2 libgps20 libgrantlee-core0 libgtlcore0.8 libgtlfragment0.8 libibus-qt1 libincidenceeditorsng4 libindicate-qt1 libkateinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcompactdisc4 libkdcraw-data libkdcraw21 libkdecorations4abi1 libkdegames6 libkdepim4 libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdgantt2 libkephal4abi1 libkexiv2-11 libkexiv2-data libkipi-data libkipi9 libkleo4 libkmanagesieve4 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1 libkontactinterface4 libkpgp4 libkrossui4 libksane-data libksane0 libksba8 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4 libksieve4 libksieveui4 libksignalplotter4 libktnef4 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent4 libktpchat0 libktpcommoninternalsprivate3 libkunitconversion4 libkwineffects1abi4 libkwinglutils1abi1 libkwinnvidiahack4 libkworkspace4abi2 liblastfm1 liblightdm-qt-2-0 libllvm3.0 libloudmouth1-0 libmailcommon4 libmailimporter4 libmessagecomposer4 libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4 libmessageviewer4 libmuonprivate1 libmygpo-qt1 libokularcore1abi1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenconnect2 libopenctl0.8 libopenjpeg2 libopenshiva0.8 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasmaclock4abi3 libplasmagenericshell4 libpoppler-qt4-4 libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libqalculate5 libqalculate5-data libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgpgme1 libqimageblitz4 libqoauth1 libqtglib-2.0-0 libqtgstreamer-0.10-0 libqtgstreamerui-0.10-0 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libqtshiva0.1 libreoffice-kde libreoffice-style-oxygen libruby1.9.1 libsolidcontrol4abi2 libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2 libspnav0 libsyndication4 libtag-extras1 libtaskmanager4abi3 libtelepathy-logger-qt4-1 libtelepathy-qt4-2 libtemplateparser4 libweather-ion6 libyaml-0-2 libzip2 lightdm-kde-greeter muon muon-installer muon-notifier muon-updater okular okular-extra-backends oxygen-cursor-theme partitionmanager pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-widget-facebook plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-kimpanel plasma-widget-menubar plasma-widget-message-indicator plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widget-telepathy-chat plasma-widget-telepathy-presence plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text print-manager python-pyudev python3-pykde4 python3-pyqt4 python3-sip qapt-deb-installer quassel quassel-data rdesktop rekonq ruby ruby1.9.1 skanlite software-properties-kde systemsettings tasks-icons ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt usb-creator-kde userconfig && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

...but now, I don't have any graphical interface and the Internet doesn't work anymore.

What can I do? Where should I start the debug?

I think that some important packages were removed.

I have terminal access, and I can copy files from another computer that is connected to the Internet (if this is needed).

Is there any way to *repair* it via an installation CD/DVD?

Comment: Where did you get that list of stuff to remove?

Comment: @Seth From [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/653/148451). Anyway, I need the solution... :-)

Comment: *Note, this applies only to Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal). If you're using 12.04, go here. If you're using 11.10, go here. If you're using 10.04, go here.* I wouldn't use that method again ;)

Comment: Use [this method](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451620/how-to-completely-remove-kubuntu-desktop) for a sure fire. It is really more flexible.

Comment: And the moral of the story is, don't blindly remove hundreds of important-looking packages :)

Comment: @Thomas Sure, I learned the lesson! But now I have to fix my mistake. Latest time I *fixed* it with a clean installation of OS, but now I want to learn how to fix it without a reinstallation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first step is getting Apt connected to the internet... You have more than one option here:

- Do you have the option of plugging an ethernet cable in? This *should* bring a connection up straight away and if it doesn't check that `/etc/network/interfaces` has something along the lines of:

  ```
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
  ```
- If that's a no-go, use `nmcli` assuming Network Manager is still installed (`man nmcli` should help lots). You'll need to list your available connections and then start your wifi up with something like:

  ```
  $ nmcli c
  NAME              UUID      TYPE                 
  Home              03e52aa   802-11-wireless    Sat 24 May 2014 21:43:00 BST
  $ sudo nmcli c up id Home
  ```
- You could learn how to manually connect. I'll be honest, there's a reason Network Manager exists. Unless you're using a simple wired connection, this isn't simple.
- If you nuked Network Manager too (or it doesn't work) I think I would fall back to `chroot`ing your install from within a LiveCD (with a working network connection). It's not as hard as it sounds.

  1. Boot to the LiveCD (Select Try Ubuntu).
  2. Set up a network connection like you normally would.
  3. Open a terminal and run `sudo fdisk -l` and note the /dev/sdX# name of your install's partition. In this example I assume `/dev/sda1`.
  4. Mount it with `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` — If you have mounted it as something else (eg if you used Nautilus and it mounted as `/media/ubuntu/...`) you need to replace `/mnt` in the following two commands with its actual mount point.
  5. Cross-mount various system things. You don't need to understand or change this line:

     ```
     for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
     ```
  6. Chroot in: `sudo chroot /mnt`. You are now effectively root on your old install.

---

Anyway, once you're connected, this gets a lot more simple. Just run:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: *The program `nmcli` is currently not installed.* - So, I guess that the network manager is nuked.

Comment: @IonicăBizău That's a fair assessment. The `chroot` method looks hard but it's very easy once you get going. And try plugging a cable in. That might autoconnect and solve a lot of pain.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to install gnome 
Sudo apt-get install gnome-xxx
Xxx=version 
After installing gnome install synaptic mgr n add /remove all the programs u want 
Edit:

Check out fr light weight desktop environments

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gtk2-engines-xfce

Download it on ur phone 
Connect ur phone to ur system 
Go to /media/device path 
Install the desktop environment and get a gui

After that get the wireless driver package for your system and install with ur gui

Comment: I don't have Internet connection... So, `apt-get install ...` won't work...

Comment: Ok so download gnome on ur phone, connect it to the lappy using usb goto /media /path where gnome is and install it from der

Comment: For example download this lightweight environment and get things working temporarily and once u have internet install everything back http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gtk2-engines-xfce