# remove plasma-desktop

Tags: 19.10, plasma

I wanted to test plasma-desktop so I installed it with:

```
sudo apt install plasma-desktop
```

It installed a bunch of packages as expected occupying 417Mb of disk space. I tried the DE for a while and decided to get rid of it, so I ran:

```
sudo apt purge --autoremove plasma-desktop
```

This however only removed 174Mb of the original 417Mb. How do I get rid of the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting inspiration from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/484905/27968) I opened the `/var/log/apt/history.log` file, copied the packages that were installed by the `plasma-desktop` meta package (had to do some cleaning by removing the brackets, commas and `:amd64`) and then I ran:

`sudo apt purge --autoremove looooooong package list pasted from text editor`

The remaining ~284Mb of packages are gone and **importantly** without breaking the system.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for that great answer.

I copied all the packages and put them into a file (apt-kde-packages), then filtered with the command

```
for i in $(cat apt-kde-packages); do echo $i | grep -v "(" | grep -v ")" | awk -F ":" '{ print $1 }'; done > apt-list-kde
```

```
sudo apt remove $(cat apt-list-kde) -y
```