# the font of gnome suddenly became weird

Tags: gnome, xorg, fonts

I'm using ubuntu 10.04. The font of gnome became very weird when I surfed the Internet.

[image: Screenshot]

I have used it for several months since the 10.04 is released. And I always install all the updates. It's the first time to meet such problem. I'm wondering what's the root cause.

Comment: What website did you surf to when that happened?

Comment: I think you have a problem whit the video card driver you can add some configuration of pc ... or `dmesg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have restarted the system to get things work again. The weird issue doesn't reproduce until now.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a look at the question ["Reset gnome font configuration?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4989/reset-gnome-font-configuration) which has an answer saying how to reset the GNOME font configuration, which I include a summary of below.

Try running the following in a terminal (Applications->Accessories->Terminal):

```
gconftool-2 --unset /desktop/gnome/interface/font_name
gconftool-2 --unset /desktop/gnome/interface/document_font_name
gconftool-2 --unset /desktop/gnome/interface/monospace_font_name
gconftool-2 --unset /apps/metacity/general/titlebar_font
gconftool-2 --unset /apps/nautilus/preferences/desktop_font
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have restarted the system to get things work again. The weird issue doesn't reproduce until now.

Comment: @Kane (assuming the issue doesn't come up for you again) it is perfectly acceptable on this site to "answer your own question" - I suggest you do that in this case, for the benefit of anyone else with a similar problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot like glyph cache corruption. That's certainly not a real font or character set, but instead it is chopped up and mixed around pieces of the regular latin alphabet. You also have some random corruption in the form of those dashed lines on the right hand side.

This kind of bug is usually caused by your video card drivers, although it is not usually this severe. For example see the screenshots on this bug report:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=495323

It can also be caused by an overheating or failing video card or other hardware problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your fonts configurations are on ~/.font.conf Try to rename it and restart your computer. If it works I think you can delete it, though you can keep it.