# How do I change fonts and adjust their size?

Tags: fonts

I've been finding fonts on the internet and [installing them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts) on my system.

What's the easiest way to change my fonts? I would prefer an easy to use graphical way, but answers with command line recommendations are also welcome.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

### Ubuntu 18.04 and later versions

The latest Ubuntu uses GNOME Shell. You can change the fonts using the "GNOME Tweaks" (`gnome-tweak-tool`) program.

Install the program using Ubuntu Software:

[image]

And change the font and font size.

[image]

### 13.04 - 17.04

For Unity interface users, customisation of fonts can be done using [unity-tweak-tool [image: Install unity-tweak-tool]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool)

[image]

[image]

[image]

### [For 12.04](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/myunity):

For Unity interface users, they have their own tweak-tool. Customisation of Fonts in 12.04 can be done through [myunity [image: Install myunity]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/myunity)

[image]

Comment: So, I have to download a special package to change the font?  Surely, you can't be serious?

Comment: @StevePitchers : I am.  And don't call me Shirley!

Comment: At version 15.10, we still need to use 2 (two) 3rd party tools for such "**System Settings**": "**Unity Tweak Tool**" gets updated better, but it still lacks a number of features that "**Ubuntu Tweak**" includes such as "*Desktop Font*".

Comment: It seems any "tweak" utility is not found for ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 33):

In Oneiric (11.10), I wasn't interested in installing GNOME Shell just to change font sizes. This will do it via command-line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name 'Sans 10'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Ubuntu 10'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Ubuntu Mono 11'
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font 'Ubuntu 10'
gconftool --set /apps/metacity/general/titlebar_font 'Ubuntu Bold 10' --type STRING
```

The fontfaces are the same as in default Oneiric, but sized down to what looked like much more manageable sizes.

Answer (score 21):

## For 11.04 and earlier:

Right click on the desktop and select "Change Desktop Background" and then click the Fonts tab. Couldn't be easier!

(NB: After playing with these setting you may wish to [reset your font configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4989/reset-gnome-font-configuration).)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 16):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font 'Ubuntu 10'
```

Where `Ubuntu 10` is the font and size you want to use. It defaults at `Ubuntu 11`.

Answer (score 13):

- Install Advanced Settings (aka `gnome-tweak-tool`) from the Software Center

[image]

- Click the dash button or press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key,search for `Advanced Settings` and launch it.

[image]

- Click on Fonts and adjust the Font settings .

[image]

Comment: Is this the same as @fossfreedom's answer above?

Comment: @zpletan Yes original I answered this on another question but then these questions were merged.

Answer (score 12):

### For Ubuntu 11.10 and newer

You can also install DConf Editor ("dconf-tools" package [only a few KB]) from Ubuntu Software Center.

#### To change fonts and/or their size

1. Launch the DConf Editor;
2. Open "org" -> "gnome" -> "desktop" -> "interface" in the left pane;
3. In the right pane, you'll find "document-font-name", "font-name" and "monospace-font-name". You can replace the font name and/or its size by the one you wish for each parameter;
4. Open "org" -> "gnome" -> "nautilus" -> "desktop" in the left pane;
5. In the right pane, you'll find "font". You can type the name of the font you wish followed by its size (Example : "Ubuntu 11") as value.

#### To change fonts hinting and/or antialiasing

1. Launch the DConf Editor;
2. Open "org" -> "gnome" -> "settings-daemon" -> "plugins" -> "xsettings" in the left pane;
3. In the right pane, you'll find "hinting" and "antialiasing". You can select the value you wish for the parameters.

DConf Editor gives useful information for the selected parameter thanks to the fields "Summary" and "Description".

The old gnome-appearance-properties is not available under Ubuntu 11.10 and newer.

Comment: +1 But this doesn't help with changing fonts and their size.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I originally answered another question which was only about "hinting" and "antialiasing" but it has been merged with this more complete one. I'm going to add missing information to my answer...

Answer (score 5):

Aleksandar is correct.  You can change the system font settings by installing gnome-tweak-tool (`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`).  However, it should be also noted that at this time, doing so also forces you to install all of GNOME-Shell, mutter, clutter, and about 20 other packages.

It's far from the end of the world, but it seems excessive just to change system fonts.  (Confession: I did it anyway :).

I doubt it *actually* needs these things since the tool itself runs fine under Unity, however that's the way the package dependencies are currently set up.

Also note:  The fact that you can't change the system fonts from "Appearance" any longer is not a design decision made by Ubuntu developers.  These settings were removed from GNOME 3 by upstream GNOME.  That this change appears in 11.10 is a result of the migration from GNOME 2.x to GNOME 3 libraries and tools.

Answer (score 3):

If you install Ubuntu-Tweak, you can change the font settings from their own tab. It is not yet at a stable version however, so the general "use at your own risk" warning applies.

The benefit is: you don't need to install GNOME-Shell.

[image: Ubuntu Tweak Font settings]

To install it, first [add](https://launchpad.net/+help/soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html) this PPA:

```
ppa:tualatrix/next
```

and then install ubuntu-tweak in the software center.

---

There is also another option, which is less "official", but works well. It is a font settings dialogue for the GNOME Control Center.

You can get it here: http://gnomefiles.org/content/show.php/GNOME+Font+Settings?content=146126

Example:
[image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Use Gnome Tweak tool

Install it using the below commands in the terminal.

---

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak

---

Once installed goto Tweaks>>fonts

[image: ubuntu]

Comment: Also can use "MyUnity"

Answer (score 2):

The gnome-tweak-tool now supports changing all Gnome desktop fonts.

[image]

Comment: I do not see that option.

Answer (score 1):

**Per user in GTK3 3.17+ ...**

> This has worked for me, but I'm actually on GTK3 version 3.24.10. My
>   research though indicates this has been a problem since 3.17.

Change the `gtk-font-name` setting in `~/.config/gtk-3.0`. The value should include the font name and size such as...

```
gtk-font-name=Helvetica 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnome-tweak-tool.Search it in synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find it either.

I came to the conclusion that installing an app called MyUnity was the most reasonable solution for now. In the Ubuntu Software Centre search for: MyUnity, or:

```
sudo apt-get install myunity
```

Once installed and launched, try tweaking the settings under "font."

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04 `gnome-tweak-tool` has been renamed to `gnome-tweaks`.

```
apt install gnome-tweaks
gnome-tweaks
```