# How do I change fonts & icons in a theme?

Tags: fonts, 11.10, themes, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts)

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. I was slightly annoyed to find no easy way to change the icons and fonts on the appearances window. Apparently, you have to choose a theme and live with it's default settings. I'm used to using varieties of window borders and icons on a theme.

Does anyone know how to make it easier to change the fonts and icons on my default Ubuntu theme?