# How can I change the system font sizes?

Tags: fonts, 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change fonts & icons in a theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59919/how-do-i-change-fonts-icons-in-a-theme)
>   [How do I change the font DPI settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60044/how-do-i-change-the-font-dpi-settings)

The default font sizes are much too large for me. In previous versions of Ubuntu, I could do this through the "Appearance" menu, but this option seems to be gone in Ubuntu 11.10 beta 1. Is there any way to change the system font sizes in Ubuntu 11.10?