# Where have the font settings gone in 11.10/Oneiric Ocelot?

Tags: 11.10, fonts, font-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

Since the shake-up of all the settings screens, how on earth does one edit their font settings? Particularly the rendering/aliasing/hinting options.

Comment: oli - does this question and answer help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size/59920#59920