# How to change the default monospaced font?

Tags: 11.10, fonts, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

In Oneiric Ocelot, the default monospaced font in "Ubuntu Mono" with size 13; I can see it from the gedit Preferences. In this screenshot you can also see this font:

[image: gedit system font]

The 13 size is too large for me, and I don't like changing it in every program that use system font.

How can I see and change this default font configution? In the control panel there is now only the Theme selection, without any customization feature (and I think this is very bad for a Linux OS...).

Thank you

Comment: you're right, sorry I did not find it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `gnome-tweak-tool`.
Then you will find it as "Advanced Settings" (Impostazioni Avanzate)