# How to change desktop font and font size

Tags: 11.10, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

The desktop's font is too big. Also, I want to change the font.

`gnome-tweak-tool` did not have the option for that.