# Why doesn't the Gnome Tweak Tool change the desktop fonts?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, fonts, gnome-tweak-tool

I've seen that the Gnome Tweak Tool is not having any effect on the desktop fonts. And the only way to do it is

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font 'Ubuntu 10'
```

which I read here 
[How to change desktop font and font size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67244/how-to-change-desktop-font-and-font-size)

Why is this happening? Is it a bug ?

Comment: I haven't tried a lot of tweaking with the GNOME Tweak Tool yet on my own systems, but sometimes the changes don't take effect immediately. Have you tried logging out and logging back in?

Comment: Yes I have done that too :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading @Pisu's comment on the linked answer (for 11.10), it looks like you need to have the package `gnome-shell` installed for this to take effect. You can still use Unity, just grab the additional packages from the Software Center.

Comment: I am on 18.10, and have gnome-shell installed and still have the problem described by the OP.