# How to change desktop only font color?

Tags: gnome, customization

My desktop font are not so legible with some background, so i want the old gnome behaviour.
I managed to choose a custom desktop font following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67244/how-to-change-desktop-font-and-font-size), but i want to change color and possibly a text shadow. It's theme depending? what i have to edit?

I'm using 11.10, both Gnome Shell and Unity.

Comment: Is this link what you need ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the file: `gnome-applications.css`, located probably in `/usr/share/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME/gtk-3.0`

The CSS class responding to desktop icon text is `.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item`.

When you change the color, you have to do more than <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and `r`, it's necessary to kill the Nautilus desktop instance. Simply run `killall nautilus`, and then open some windowed Nautilus instance -- it should launch the desktop.

Comment: Thank goodness you answered this!! I've been looking for an answer to this for a while :)