# Themes, fonts - why can't u change it anymore?

Tags: 11.10, fonts, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

Why is it not possible anymore the change the themes and fonts?

Comment: what version of ubuntu? if 11.10 - does this answer your question?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size/59920#59920

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the gnome-tweak-tool

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

It will give you some control over the fonts and themes on your system, though not as intuitive for installing new themes - you have to do that manually.

Also, if you try to change the desktop background you'll be given the opportunity to select a window theme from there.