# I can't seem to change the font rendering setting?

Tags: 11.10, fonts, font-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

How do I change it from what seems to be no dithering and ultra-sharp fonts to a more smooth appearence, and from RGB to mono?

Comment: Please edit your question with what you have tried in this question and answer - and what didnt work.   Thanks.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `gnome-tweak-tool`, it seems to have an option for that.

Comment: that is for 11.10 - the OP question is for 11.04...

Comment: whoops, I meant to say 11.10,

Comment: in 11.04 there was an Appearance panel that handled font rendering (which is missing in Oneiric)