# How do I select the system fonts in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, fonts, system, default

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

Before 11.10 one could change the system default fonts in the Appearance settings changer, but now one can only change the wallpaper. Is there some gconf key one can use?

Comment: yes the solution is exactly similar to what Jorge pointed to if u still want to know how then use gnome-tweak-tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the software center look for `gnome-tweak-tool` and install it, it will show up as `Advanced settings` in the launcher.

Comment: why post an answer that is identical to the duplicate comment?