# How to change font hinting settings?

Tags: 11.10, unity, font-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10, and I wish to change the font rendering options (medium hinting, enable subpixel rendering). How do I do that? The Appearance icon in the system settings window only allows me to change the desktop wallpaper. Folks on the forums are recommending that I install gnome-tweak-tool, but it seems to drag in about a hundred Mb of dependencies with itself, and I don't want that. Is there any other way? Can I launch the old gnome-appearance-properties applet somehow?