# How do I change the default font for the terminal and gedit?

Tags: ubuntu-font-family

I want to change the `font style` in `terminal` and for default `gedit` as well.So how to change the `font type in Ubuntu 12.04`?Any help and suggestions will be appreciable.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

Comment: Not a total duplicate. Although changing system fonts is covered in the link, changing fonts in terminal and gedit are not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To install gnome-tweak-tool in Ubuntu 12.04-20.04 open the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

In fonts you can change the systemwide font.

For gedit:

[image: gedit]
<sub>(source: [iloveubuntu.net](http://iloveubuntu.net/pictures_me/gedit%20font%2013%20mono.png))</sub>

For terminal:
[image: terminal]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the editor but for the terminal just change the font for the default profile from the

`Edit -> Profile` menu

Cheers

S

Answer (score 0):

For the terminal, you can right-click in the content window (not the title bar), and choose 'Profiles', then 'Profile preferences'.  You then get the same dialog as showed in [0x00F's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/131489/172844)