# What was the default font for Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

I have installed `Ubuntu 12.04` on my system.Everything is going fine.But I thing I got that it has `different font by default`.So I want to change it in `Gedit` and `Terminal` from this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131472/how-do-i-change-the-default-font-for-the-terminal-and-gedit).But I want to know which font was installed on `Ubuntu 11.04 by default`.I want that font to be my default font.So can some one tell me what was the default font for `Ubuntu 11.04`?Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The standard font should have been `Ubuntu Light` as indicated in [this blog post](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2011/04/ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal-released.html) on Ubuntu Vibes.

You can see this particular font and download the whole Ubuntu font family here: http://font.ubuntu.com/#charset-light

Answer (score 1):

Do you really mean 11.04 - Natty Narwal or 10.04 Lucid Lynx? Since 10.10 Ubuntu uses the Ubuntu Font, 10.04 used [DejaVu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dejavu/) which can be installed as `ttf-dejavu` package.

I think the same applies to the Monotype variants.

Comment: I want the default font used by the `Ubuntu 11.04`.