# Where is the font size selection tool that used to be in the appearance area?

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

I need to resize the system fonts for the apps but I can't find it anymore, it used to be in Appearance but not anymore.
Help