# Fonts in Firefox weird after installing kubuntu-desktop

Tags: firefox, kde, fonts

I've installed KDE with the intentions to try it out, but now, after removing it and going back to Unity, I noticed that the fonts in Firefox are still like in KDE.

How can I revert the font type to before KDE was installed?

Comment: Try to reconfigure fonts . See this question [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

Comment: All the fonts are already set to default in there, and this only happens with Firefox, all other apps are fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is removing .fonts.conf placed by KDE. This restored the fonts to normal.

Comment: Hey, where is the .fonts.conf in Ubuntu?

Comment: Hidden in your home directory. Press Ctrl+H to show.

Comment: the new directory is ~/.config/fonts.conf

Answer (score 3):

**For Ubuntu 14.04**, remove the `.fonts.conf`  file in `~/.config/fontconfig`

```
rm ~/.config/fontconfig/.fonts.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

- edit->preferences
- Click, 'Content'
- Go down to fonts and colors/colours and change the font to whichever you would prefer.

Comment: It's set to the defaults, and changing it doesn't change interface fonts.

Comment: Well then, sorry you're flipped in as far as my knowledge of Ubuntu. But I'll leave this answer here in case someone comes across your question with a question that is answered by my answer.