# Firefox display issue after kubuntu-desktop installation

Tags: kubuntu, firefox

My system specs are as follows.

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 21.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.86.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-22-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Memory: 7.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
```

I installed kubuntu-desktop on my system and everything looks fine except the firefox.

```
~$ sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends
[sudo] password for ajayc: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
alsa-base kubuntu-settings-desktop language-selector-common linux-sound-base software-properties-qt
Suggested packages:
apmd alsa-oss oss-compat
Recommended packages:
apport-kde avahi-daemon cdrdao cryptsetup elisa firefox fonts-indic fonts-khmeros-core fonts-lao fonts-lklug-sinhala fonts-noto-cjk
fonts-sil-abyssinica fonts-sil-padauk fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-tibetan-machine go-mtpfs gstreamer-qapt gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gwenview
kaccounts-integration kate kde-config-gtk-style-preview kde-config-tablet kde-config-whoopsie kde-spectacle kdeconnect
kdenetwork-filesharing kio-audiocd kmahjongg kmines konversation kpat krdc ksudoku ktorrent kubuntu-wallpapers kubuntu-web-shortcuts
kwalletmanager kwin-addons libnss-mdns libreoffice-calc libreoffice-impress libreoffice-kf5 libreoffice-plasma libreoffice-style-breeze
libreoffice-writer mlocate muon partitionmanager pastebinit pavucontrol-qt phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer pinentry-qt
plasma-calendar-addons plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-discover plasma-discover-backend-snap plasma-runners-addons
plasma-systemmonitor plasma-vault plasma-wallpapers-addons plasma-widgets-addons plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo
plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text print-manager pulseaudio-module-bluetooth qapt-deb-installer qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel
qt5-image-formats-plugins skanlite snapd thunderbird usb-creator-kde xdg-desktop-portal-kde
The following NEW packages will be installed:
alsa-base kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-settings-desktop language-selector-common linux-sound-base software-properties-qt
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 854 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,251 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 language-selector-common all 0.216 [246 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 linux-sound-base all 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7 [13.3 kB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 alsa-base all 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7 [145 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 software-properties-qt all 0.99.13.1 [25.7 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 kubuntu-settings-desktop all 1:21.10.2 [421 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 kubuntu-desktop amd64 1.408 [3,526 B]
Fetched 854 kB in 4s (214 kB/s)             
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package language-selector-common.
(Reading database ... 197347 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-language-selector-common_0.216_all.deb ...
Unpacking language-selector-common (0.216) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-sound-base.
Preparing to unpack .../1-linux-sound-base_1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-sound-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package alsa-base.
Preparing to unpack .../2-alsa-base_1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7_all.deb ...
Unpacking alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package software-properties-qt.
Preparing to unpack .../3-software-properties-qt_0.99.13.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking software-properties-qt (0.99.13.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package kubuntu-settings-desktop.
Preparing to unpack .../4-kubuntu-settings-desktop_1%3a21.10.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking kubuntu-settings-desktop (1:21.10.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package kubuntu-desktop.
Preparing to unpack .../5-kubuntu-desktop_1.408_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kubuntu-desktop (1.408) ...
Setting up linux-sound-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7) ...
Setting up language-selector-common (0.216) ...
Setting up software-properties-qt (0.99.13.1) ...
Setting up alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7) ...
Setting up kubuntu-settings-desktop (1:21.10.2) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/newt/palette.original to provide /etc/newt/palette (newt-palette) in manual mode
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-21-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Setting up kubuntu-desktop (1.408) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu2) ...
~$
```

Screenshot of Firefox before installation of kubuntu-desktop
[image]

Screenshot of Firefox after installation of kubuntu-desktop. See how big is the password dialog and text looks.

[image: Screenshot of Firefox after installation of kubuntu-desktop]

The issue occurs only with firefox. Chrome, thunderbird and other app look absolutely fine.

Comment: Changing desktop environments on an installed system is very messy. This is why most distros, including Ubuntu, come with different releases with different desktop environments. In Ubuntu these are called [flavours](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours).  The flavor of Ubuntu with KDE is Kubuntu.  If you want to use KDE, I suggest you reinstall Kubuntu. Otherwise you're probably going to encounter a lot of issues and general weirdness.

Comment: Can you get any clues from this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/209725/fonts-in-firefox-weird-after-installing-kubuntu-desktop

Comment: @darth_epoxy: no this does not solve the issue. There is a file a ~/.config/fontconfig/font.conf but nothing happens when I delete it.