# How do I change window title font size using command line in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, command-line, fonts

Using 12.10, I can apply all but the last line in this answer: [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/a/67260/134244) to change font sizes.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name 'Sans 10'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Ubuntu 10'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Ubuntu Mono 11'
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font 'Ubuntu 10'
gconftool --set /apps/metacity/general/titlebar_font 'Ubuntu Bold 10' --type STRING
```

The last line referencing gconftool has no effect on window title font size. What is the correct command?

Comment: The method described in that answer is for Ubuntu 11.10 so if you're running anything newer it probably won't work. Please add a tag or edit your answer to say which version of Ubuntu you are running and the community can try to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The settings are in gsettings now. This should do it:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font 'Ubuntu 10'`