# change default font in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, fonts

Linux OS is said to be super customisable. But, how do I change the default font in Ubuntu? I could not find any easy method to do this. Some people suggested using dconf tool or Gnome tweak or Unity tweak tool.

Point is I want to do it manually so that I know how things work behind the screen.

OS: Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Please mention whether you are using Gnome or Unity. If you're using Gnome, go for `gnome-tweak-tool`. For Unity, there's `unity-tweak-tool`.

Comment: As others have suggested, there are apps for it. But, what do they do behind the screens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to Unity Tweak Tool, you can use **Dconf Editor** which is pre-installed in 13.04.

After you open Dconf Editor, go to **org** > **gnome** > **desktop** > **interface**. Here you can see font-name, monospace-font-name, document-font-name, text-scaling-factor, etc.

To change titlebar font, you should go to **org** > **gnome** > **desktop** > **wm** > **preferences** where you can find titlebar-font.

You can also search for *font* and see all settings about fonts.

[image: Dconf Editor]

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

To change the fonts, you can use the Gnome tweak tool.  To install it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Once installed, run it, and click on fonts to change the default font.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear