# Changing Font Size in Applications

Tags: graphics, resolution, display, fonts, macbook-pro

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Macbook Pro 11-1. Because of the Retina display, the resolution absolutely needs to be 2560x1600 (I have a 13 inch). However, that obviously doesn't work too well with an OS that's not designed for this specific need in mind. I have changed around a lot of things, but especially with apps [such as Spotify](http://community.spotify.com/t5/ideas/v2/ideapage/blog-id/ideaexchange/article-id/321/page/1#comments) with developers that do not add an option to change fonts, I still get teeny tiny font everywhere that really bugs me. Is there any way that I can edit these things?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

Comment: I'm asking about font in terms of editing other apps, not just Unity and such. It's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Universal Access has a "large text" option.  Additionally, there's a universal keyboard shortcut that inflates or deflates text in most applications.

Hold CTRL and scroll up/down or hold CTRL and press + or -.