# All fonts look weird in emails and on websites, how can I fix this?

Tags: firefox, fonts, chromium, thunderbird

I've just installed Ubuntu and my fonts look weird on website and in emails. 
Below are some screenshots of thunderbird and chromium.

The problem occurs in the following programs:

- Chromium
- Firefox
- Thunderbird

how can I fix it?

In Thunderbird:
[image: email also with same fonts]

In Chromium:
[image]

Comment: Right first we need to know if this Ubuntu or a web browser issue, I assume you use Firefox.

Comment: no iam opening it in chrome not firefox..did all the possible settings for same in chrome

Comment: So you have this in both chrome and firefox

Comment: is it the same issue if you use firefox? Also what version of chrome do you have? Have you tried using chromium?

Comment: @markkirby yes it is coming in chromium and firefox

Comment: Then it's a problem with fonts and not the browser themselves. So go into system settings and look for fonts, to see if you can change it.

Comment: @Alvar in settings only Fonts viewer comes where i cannot change anything

Comment: Look at this answer, http://askubuntu.com/a/59920/10698

Comment: @Alvar thanks a lot for article the fonts of my PC are now changed and problem with emails is solved...with Social Media the result is still same

Comment: I would reinstall the browsers.

Comment: @Alvar thank you alvar for help. Really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change your font please install unity-tweak-tool from software center, run it from dash and and choose fonts.

Also if the option "hinting" is not set to slight please do so,

EDIT We can do the same thing for chrome and see if that helps there

Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar. Select Settings. Click Show advanced settings and go to the "Languages" section Then default font and encoding Choose any font and see if this fixes your issue and let me know

Comment: i did install this , my email fonts problem is solved but the social media website fonts are still coming weird. And biggest strange fact is that only websites related to social media are coming with those fonts. kindly help

Comment: all the problems are solved related to fonts in chromium..but dont know why fb, linkedin fonts display are not getting changed

Comment: Are you using web app or browser versions of linkedin and facebook ?

Comment: browser versions

Comment: Here is an extension for chrome to force all websites to use your selected fonts https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ubuntu-1010-unified-font/gmpnnplimbnbmdaigmnajmbdcinhpddj?hl=en

Comment: sorry that link is out dated this one should be better https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E5%BC%BA%E5%88%B6%E7%BD%91%E9%A1%B5%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E5%AD%97%E4%BD%93/hckjchjpkmbihoocajjpjajkggbccgee?hl=en

Comment: doesnt seems to help..should i reinstall the browsers?

Comment: Try but do it like this - sudo apt-get remove --purge chromium-browser && apt-get autoremove - sudo apt-get install chromium - sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade - This will ensure a clean and up to date install.