# All system text has shrunk after update

Tags: updates, resolution, fonts

The text for the whole system has shrunk a lot.

[image]

I think this is since the last update.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, with Kernel 3.13.0-49-generic. The screen resolution is 1280 x 800 - it hasn't changed.

Why did this happen and how can I get it back to a readable size?

Comment: As a workaround you could turn Large Text on, under Universal Access.

Answer (score 2):

[How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/q/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size) solved my problem. I simply clicked "Restore Defaults".

> For Unity interface users, customisation of fonts can be done using [unity-tweak-tool [image: Install unity-tweak-tool]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool)
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]