# Change style LibreOffice Calc

Tags: printing, 15.10, libreoffice, fonts

The problem is rather easy to explain: how to change the font size/color/boldness of the row/column numbering in a LibreOffice Calc document on Ubuntu 15.10 (LO version is the default 5.0.5.2)?

Is it possible to do it at all? How?
I need to print screen LO and use it in a PDF file for educational purposes (to teach other how to use it).
The default style, when printed and then fotocopied results in a very light shade, almost not readable.

To give an example, I would like to change the style of "A", "B", "C" and so on in this image [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l2ic.png]

Comment: Libre Office pros can be found at https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/feedback/ if that helps...

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I wait a couple of days more and then in case I write there.

Answer (score 1):

Change the operating system to use a High Contrast theme.  To do this, I clicked the System Settings icon in the Unity tray, then clicked Appearance.  The theme was set to `Ambiance (default)` which I changed to `High Contrast`.

As far as the font size, I tried using `unity-tweak-tool` to change the system default size as described in [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size), but it didn't seem to work on my system.  I didn't try very hard though.

Instead of changing the font size of the headers to be *bigger*, why not change the cell text size to be *smaller*.  Then the headers will look relatively bigger in the screen capture, which you can zoom in or enlarge as needed.

Comment: This is a very ugly workaround, though...