# Ubuntu 16.04 font aspect of gnome-terminal: how to change the height/width ratio?

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04, and I use Unity.

The gnome-terminal seem to have lost options to control its appearance and it's very disappointing... :(

For example, I checked with screenshots from the previous version, the font appears wider: indeed for fontsize 11, I could fit 93 characters on a row using a half screen, whereas only 80 now...). I am pretty sure there was an option before to control the aspect ratio of the font, and personally I prefer to have more characters on a line...

Has it disappeared forever? Is there a workaround?

Also, now, there is the scrollbar on the right that does not disappear. How to get rid of it?

Comment: Edit > Profile Preferences, change as desired

Comment: @doug There is not the setting I describe.

Comment: In 14.04 I see nothing about "aspect ratio of the font", just an option for using the system font or not. So in 16.04 which doesn't have this option set a custom font to suit (if possible). As far as removing scroll bar it's under the Scrolling tab.

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll try to set a custom font. I found the scroll bar setting, didn't search enough...

Comment: [Fontconfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontconfig) has an `aspect` property ("Stretches glyphs horizontally before hinting") you can use in [fonts.config](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html), implying you can specify a value like 0.8 to increase the height:width ratio, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, now I remember how I changed the font aspect ratio in previous Ubuntu versions. I used [unity-tweak-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/), exactly as described in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/59920/382931) (Under Appearance, Fonts, Text scaling factor). Then later I decided unity-tweak-tool was kind of a bad dangerous program and I uninstalled it, that's why I forgot I guess.

I'll try to find if there is a way to do the same without unity-tweak-tool and edit later this answer if so.

For the scrollbar, as @doug said in its comment, it's in Edit > Preferences under the "Scrolling" tab.

[EDIT: How to change the default font with dconf-editor]

Without unity-tweak-tools, dconf-editor does the job, you just need to know where to find the parameter:

1. Run `dconf-editor` in a terminal.
2. navigate to : org > gnome > desktop > interface
3. Edit the fields *monospace-font-name* and *text-scaling-factor*. In my case, I set to 'Ubuntu Mono 12' and 0.9 respectively.
4. close dconf-editor
5. in gnome-terminal, open the preferences of your profile, and choose to use the default font.

Comment: Adjusting the *text-scaling-factor* can also be performed in a single command on the command line as follows: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 0.9`

Comment: *text-scaling-factor* does not alter the height:width ratio for me.  It merely magnifies or shrinks the font proportionally.