# Restore default ubuntu Font Size

Tags: fonts, unity-tweak-tool

I've a problem regarding font size of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Some of the text are so small are some of them are quite big. Can anyone tell me what is the normal and default font size of Ubuntu and how to set them on this OS using Unity Tweak Tool.

It will also be helpful if anyone can tell me how to restore the default ubuntu Font Size. Thank you.

Comment: I think you will find this will vary with each version. What Version are you using?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Check out this post, https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size, I've never tried it though.

Comment: The default font size is 11 for the interface. Add a screenshot of your problem