# System font is unreadable. How can it be changed?

Tags: display, fonts, system-language

What can I do?

I just updated from 17.04 to 17.10 and the following display error occurs, I do not know what it can be, I can not reinstall it right now.

Is there any way to fix it?

[image: here is the error]

Comment: Try changing the font from command line by following this https://askubuntu.com/a/67260/269807