# How to reset Ubuntu Fonts?

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, lubuntu, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset gnome font configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4989/reset-gnome-font-configuration)

I've just followed some advice on askubuntu and installed gnome-shell over lubuntu. Everything went smooth, apart from the fonts that look different and ugly (as in some java programs).
I've tried with xubuntu and it's the same.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: if you have followed an answer from askubuntu , then you have to place the link too .

Answer (score 3):

Try the gnome tweak tool, open up your terminal and type.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

When it has finished just type .

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

[image]

From the menu select fonts and try some combinations until you are happy with the look. The original setup would have been.

Default font -> Ubuntu

Monospace font -> Ubuntu Mono

[image]

Comment: Thanks CoalaWeb, your post was very useful and it solved my problem. However I would like to point out that using Gnome shell over xubuntu on my Sony Vaio was not a good idea. It may be faster and take less space on HD, but fan is constantly in use and system monitor showed its 4 CPUs at about 50% load.

Answer (score -3):

Go to gnome settings application. There choose the fonts section. From here you can tweak the appearance of fonts.

Comment: Hey dude, there's no such "gnome settings application" on xubuntu or lubuntu ;)

Comment: Well he installed the gnome shell didn't he. Doesn't it come with a settings panel?