# tiny toolbar font on some apps. how to increase size?

Tags: fonts, display-resolution, scaling

[image: PencilSheep]

for some reason some apps have a tiny toolbar. most apps like chromium are fine, spotify had this issue, but there was a solution for that.

does anyone have a good idea how to increase the size of font in the troublesome apps? the rest of my system is fine, so i dont think it is a resolution or scaling problem

Comment: What version and flavor of Ubuntu are you using?  I do not recognize the desktop environment.  Have you made alterations to the desktop environment?  If so, have you reverted your changes to make sure that they are not responsible for the problems you are experiencing?  GNOME in particular can be very stubborn and buggy if you attempt to customize it beyond the settings that are available without installing "tweaks" or making changes to configuration files.  GNOME is not designed with user customization as a priority.

Comment: You are probably having a high resolution (HDPI) display. Older apps or apps using older toolkits (GTK2) may not support HDPI well.

Comment: im using Ubuntu 20.04LTS. i haven't done anything to it really besides change the wallpaper. so its pretty much set up exactly how it came, no alterations.

Comment: i have a 4k Touch screen on my Precision 5510, Nvidia Quadro M1000M. im not sure if this display is responsible for the issue. honestly im having all sorts of display issues with Ubuntu. im about to create another post for the issues im experiencing with my 2nd display.

Comment: The font along the top is not the font that is used in Ubuntu and there is not a setting where you can change this.   So you must have changed *something*...

Comment: i did change the font with i think its called gnome tweaks. i could revert it back to the original font and see if that helps. didn't think that a change in font would alter the size of the text, but i barely have a clue what I'm doing.

Comment: (https://askubuntu.com/questions/4989/how-do-i-reset-gnome-font-configuration) i followed these instructions to reset my font settings. maybe it is just a problem with PencillSheep specifically. because im opening other apps and none are having the small text issue anymore. i remember spotify having this issue and i was shown instructions on how to use the CLI to alter the text and make it bigger. could i try the same tactic here?